# Why the PUSHDATA is 65 in the first transaction in blk00000.dat?

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction

https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/4a5e1e4baab89f3a32518a88c31bc87f618f76673e2cc77ab2127b7afdeda33b?show_adv=true

The raw script is in the first transaction is:
  **41**04678afdb0fe5548271967f1a67130b7105cd6a828e03909a67962e0ea1f61deb649f6bc3f4cef38c4f35504e51ec112de5c384df7ba0b8d578a4c702b6bf11d5f**ac**

0x41 -> 65 (PUSHDATA) # **Why ?????**
0xac -> 175 (OP_CHECKSIG)

The list of OP can be found here
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/bffb35f876572737b175aa3620bbf3e62c20f444/test/functional/test_framework/script.py

There is no 0x41 OP at all~~~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opcodes between `OP_0` (`0x00`) and `OP_PUSHDATA1` (`0x4c`, `76`) (exclusive range) are push opcodes.

To push data smaller than 76 bytes, data's length, which is an opcode within that range should be used.

For example, to push `0x01020304`, which has four bytes, `0x04` should be used: `0x0401020304`.

To push `0x12`, which has one byte, prepend with `0x01`: `0x0112`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I know 0x41 is 65 , the question is 0x41 not in the current OP list.

Comment: @Capemer I hope the edit understands your question precisely.

Comment: Thanks!Just clarify with you, the last example is 0x0112?

Comment: Yup, sorry.....